# 3-dimensional cube shortest path question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, equivalence-relations

Let Q be the graph consisting of vertices and edges of a 3-dimensional cube. Two relations are defined on the vertices of Q.

•   R1={(v,w):the shortest path from v to w has an odd number of edges}.

•   R2={(v,w):the shortest path from v to w has an even number of edges.

- Exactly one of R1 and R2 is an equivalence relation
- Both R1 and R2 are equivalence relations
- None of R1 and R2 is an equivalence relation

**My thoughts:**

There is no such points (v,m) at 3-dimensional cube that have both even and odd number edges shortest path, so i would choose "None of R1 and R2 is an equivalence relation" based on this fact. -- wrong thoughts.

**correct thinking**:
Choose any element in R1, call it x. Is xRx? Choose any two elements in R1 call them x, y. If xRy is yRx? And choose any three elements in R1, call them x,y,z If xRy and yRz, is xRz? Do the same for R2.

Please help if you have any thoughts, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your thoughts. Let's take those relations one at a time. Please explain why you think $R_2$ is not an equivalence relation. Which of the three requirements for an equivalence relation fails here: reflexivity, symmetry, or transitivity?

Comment: my thinking is based on the graph, if i have a odd number of edges between two points v and m. Then i can not find any path with even number of edges in the path without repeating edges. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You are right about that, but you haven't explained what that has to do with your questions about equivalence relations. Question 1. Is $R_1$ an equivalence relation? That breaks down into three sub-questions: 1a. Is $R_1$ reflexive? 1b. Is $R_1$ symmetric? 1c. Is $R_1$ transitive. Question 2. Is $R_2$ an equivalence relation? 2a. Is $R_2$ reflexive? 2b. Is $R_2$ symmetric? 2c. Is $R_2$ transitive? So which of the six sub-questions can you answer, and what are the answers? And where does your observation about not having both an odd and an even path between the same two vertices come in?

Comment: oh... thank you for explanation, now i understand.

Comment: it seems that they all satisfy all three properties, so answer would be "Both R1 and R2 are equivalence relations", am i right?

Comment: Not exactly. $R_1$ is symmetric, but it is neither reflexive nor transitive, so it's not an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalence relation $R$, written $a \sim b$, satisfies the following properties:

- Reflexive: $a \sim a$
- Symmetric, if $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$
- Transitive: if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, then $a \sim c$.

$R_1$ is not an equivalence relation because it is not transitive: if you have an odd-length path from $a$ to $b$ and an odd-length from $b$ to $c$, then the path from $a$ to $c$ can have an even length (as adding two odds will give an even), provided it goes through $b$.
(As MJD points out correctly above, it also isn't reflexive: the path from $a$ to $a$ has length $0$ and is of even length.)

$R_2$ is an equivalence relation: we have $a \sim a$ for any $a \in V$, where $V$ is the vertex set, as the length $0$ is even. Symmetry is obvious. Transitivity is also satisfied, because two evens always add to an even. That's not satisfactory though: this answer is incomplete; see comments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I appreciate your help.

Comment: sure. good luck! with equivalence relations, always start from the definition.

Comment: Your discussion of transitivity is a little too glib. The shortest path from $a$ to $c$ does not necessarily go through $b$, so "odd + odd = even" and "even + even = even" is not the whole story. Replace the cube by a tetrahedron ($K_4$), if $a,b,c$ are three distinct vertices, the shortest path from $a$ to $b$, the shortest path from $b$ to $c$, and the shortest path from $a$ to $c$ all have odd length. For these questions about the cube, we definitely need to use the fact that the cube is a $2$-colorable graph.

Comment: @bof (You're right --- my answer is incomplete.) More important is the fact that the cube has a diameter of $4$. So the only conceivable paths from $b$ to $c$ have length $0,1,2,3$ --- you could do a case-argument easily here.

Comment: The cube has diameter $3$. The **shortest** path from $b$ to $c$ can only have length $0$,$1$,$2$, or $3$; the longest path could have length $7$, since the cube is a Hamiltonian graph.

Comment: Yes, 3. You could easily construct an argument that works on case basis, and in the possibility of a path of even length $p$, finds a complementary path of length $7-p$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $R_1$ is not an equivalence relation because it isn't reflexive.

However, $R_2$ *is* an equivalence relation, and you should prove this, as follows:  First, look up the definition of an equivalence relation, including the three properties that characterize an equivalence relation.  Then, for eac of the three properties, show that $R_2$ has that property.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.